# need help understanding a loop in "head first c#"

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm running through a book called "head first c#" and there's a part where it goes through loops that I need to figure out if they eventually end or run forever.

One of these loops the book says runs 8 times, however for the life of me it should run essentially forever.

[image: the loop in question]

It starts off with `p` and `q` equal, and runs while `q` is less than `32`, because p is equal and not less than q it skips the while loop and goes straight to: `q = p - q`; which is `q = 2 - 2`;
at this point the for loop finishes its first run and does `q = q * 2`; which is now `q = 0 * 2`;

At this point it is now impossible for q to ever go up and the for loop should run forever, and p will NEVER be less than q, meaning the while loop is never run....

So HOW THE HELL does it run 8 times?

I was expecting there to be a trick I was missing and read through it carefully a number of times but I can't find it.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to post the code as *text*, not as an image.

Comment: A quick test seems to suggest this does indeed loop forever. It is probably a mistake in the book. https://tio.run/##VYzBCoMwEETvfsUcoyCUeNR8gh8RosUFMVkT2kPJt6dJpdU@2IWdnRnjW2P3OSWzau8xvipkfNCBDB6WJoyaNlHjeBRoC3BK9j/hbndRRFa3Hjx0Mu9GyfqMFJ4LrTMEY4C71n1xUHkaXIoL8e/ij6kFn6bDEKuY0hs

Comment: thank you mouse tail, that's what i assumed as well as there are typos in a couple places, LOADS of peace fo mind hearing that and that im not just going mad xD

Comment: In these cases just type it in and try it out. It's much faster than asking online.

Answer (score 1):

You're not quite correct here, because you're missing the fact that the loop invariant always runs last.

To help you understand what's going on here, let me break this down. When the loop starts, `p` and `q` are both 2.

1. In the first iteration, you are correct that the while loop does not run, and therefore, `q` is updated to 0. The loop invariant then does `q = q * 2`, which updates it to 0.
2. In the second iteration, again the while loop does not run. In this case, `q` is then set to `p - q`, which is 2. The loop invariant then does `q = q * 2`, which sets `q` to 4.
3. In the third iteration, the while loop runs and updates `p` to 4. We then repeat the same operation as in step 1, and `q` is set to 0.
4. In the fourth iteration, the loop operates similarly to the second iteration, and `p - q` results in 4. The loop invariant then does `q = q * 2`, which sets `q` to 8.

From this it's easy to see, that each odd iteration of the loop results in `q` being zero and `p` being equal to `q` and each even iteration results in `q` being set to `2 * p`. Therefore, `q` will be equal to 32 after 8 iterations.

As an aside, if you're curious to see how a piece of code is working, you could always write it in C# and step into the code in Debugging Mode. Doing so would show you the value of all variables within scope after each line is executed.

Comment: ooh okay, thanks for explaining it ^.^, i gues si got so stuck on the whole "but 0 * 2 is 0 that i forgot that p didnt change and is still 2

Comment: @Dredin47 No problem at all. Learning the finer details of any language is difficult. Keep it up! :)